How to create stacked and clustered chart
I would like to have two bars for each quarter (one internal fraud and one external fraud), there are different deception types under each quarter.
For each bar, the no. of different deception type should be shown in the bar.
Data
How can I build a stacked and clustered chart?
This is what I want:pivot chart
I have tried to click "add" in select data: enter image description here
Does it means I need to rearrange my data? How?

Please read and update your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
